# Make own calibration dialog with comma delimiter decimal

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Is there an event similar as "FINISHED_CALIBRATION" when the style for the "calibration panel" is set to display: block? I want to create a custom calibration dialog with comma separator. I want to open own calibration dialog instead of your dialog. I check two point for calibration with  this  code:

```
const calibrationEndpoints: HTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('calibration-endpoint');
const countPoint = Array.from(calibrationEndpoints).filter(e => e.classList.contains('editable')).length;
if (countPoint === 2) {
this.openCalibrationDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please review [this sample](https://github.com/wallabyway/forge-markup-measure-extensions/blob/master/Measure/CalibrationTool.js#L313)

```
this.showPanel = function() {

    var self = this;
    const _window = this.getWindow();

    if (_calibrationPanel) {
        _window.setTimeout(function () { _calibrationPanel.requestedSizeTextbox.focus();}, 0);
        _calibrationPanel.setVisible(true);
        _calibrationPanel.updatePanelPosition(_measurement.indicator.labelPosition, _measurement.indicator.p1, _measurement.indicator.p2, _measurement.indicator.calibrationLabel.clientHeight);
        self.addWindowEventListener("keyup", function onKeyUp(e){
            var key = e.key || String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            if (key == "Escape" && self.isActive()) {
                self.hidePanel();
                self.clearSize();
                self.showAddCalibrationLabel();
                
                self.removeWindowEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        _viewer.dispatchEvent({ type: MeasureCommon.Events.OPEN_CALIBRATION_PANEL_EVENT, data: {size: _selectedSize, units: _selectedUnits } });
    }
};
```